# How do I keep the spaces in equations when aligning them in odd places?

Tags: equations, alignment

In the middle example the space between the $\equiv$ and the right side is wrong. Can I not put the alignment & anywhere I want?

[image: example]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
a + b \equiv c\\
x + y \equiv z.
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
a + b \equiv& c\\
x + y \equiv& z.
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
a + b &\equiv c\\
x + y &\equiv z.
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `&` usually goes *before* the relation sign that serves as alignment point.

Comment: If for some reason, you have to align by the r.h.s., write `\equiv {} &`.

Answer (score 2):

> Can I not put the alignment `&` anywhere I want?

No, you cannot. As you discovered yourself in the third example, the correct spacing was obtained when you put the alignment tab `&` *before* the relation symbol. If you put it *after* the relation symbol, you get wrong spacing as in your second example.

Why? Let’s use your `align*` example. In [`amsmath.dtx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amsmath/amsmath.dtx) we found the following code involving the `align` family of environments:

```
\def\align@preamble{%
   &\hfil
    \strut@
    \setboxz@h{\@lign$\m@th\displaystyle{##}$}%
    \ifmeasuring@\savefieldlength@\fi
    \set@field
    \tabskip\z@skip
   &\setboxz@h{\@lign$\m@th\displaystyle{{}##}$}%
    \ifmeasuring@\savefieldlength@\fi
    \set@field
    \hfil
    \tabskip\alignsep@
}
```

The most important things to notice are: `$\m@th\displaystyle{##}$` and `$\m@th\displaystyle{{}##}$`. These two lines reveal that when a “right- and left-aligned two-column” pair is created, the left-aligned second column has an empty atom `{}` inserted at the beginning, and this is how `amsmath` gets the spacing around relation symbol right (*but only if you put the alignment tab before the relation symbol*).

Similar implementation goes with the `aligned` family of environments, the `split` and `multline` environments.

---

I do *not* encourage the following hack! I consider changing the source code of something as stable as `amsmath` dangerous and an extremely bad practice. **I hope this next example illustrates why `amsmath` does not add `{}` to both columns.**

Just to show you what would happen if I change the definition of the right-aligned first column:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{amsfonts}% <- you don't need `amsfonts' if `amssymb' is loaded
\usepackage{amssymb}

% Do not do the following! It is just for this illustration!
\makeatletter
\def\align@preamble{%
   &\hfil
    \strut@
%    \setboxz@h{\@lign$\m@th\displaystyle{##}$}% <- commented out
    \setboxz@h{\@lign$\m@th\displaystyle{##{}}$}% <- inserted here
    \ifmeasuring@\savefieldlength@\fi
    \set@field
    \tabskip\z@skip
   &\setboxz@h{\@lign$\m@th\displaystyle{{}##}$}%
    \ifmeasuring@\savefieldlength@\fi
    \set@field
    \hfil
    \tabskip\alignsep@
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\subsection*{I~do not encourage this hack! This leads to bad coding habits}
\begin{align*}
a + b \equiv c \qquad\qquad & a + b \equiv +1 \\
x + y \equiv z \qquad\qquad & x + y \equiv -1.
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
a + b \equiv& c \quad \text{Seems fine} & a + b \equiv& +1 \quad \text{Wrong spacing!}\\
x + y \equiv& z                         & x + y \equiv& -1.
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
a + b &\equiv c \quad \text{This is good} & a + b &\equiv +1 \quad \text{Correct spacing!}\\
x + y &\equiv z                           & x + y &\equiv -1.
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image: align spacing]