# Spacing from phantom symbol being consumed by summation symbol

Tags: math-mode, align, phantom

## The problem

I have found that when I add a `phantom{{}+{}}` in an aligned environment, if this is followed by a summation symbol, the horizontal spacing is not the same as if I had actually used `+`.

#### Examples

[image]

If I vertically raise the lower symbol we can see that **they are not vertically aligned**.
[image]

However, they are aligned if I omit the `+` and the `phantom`
[image]

#### Why bother?

Because when I have a series of multi-line inequalities I don't like it when authors have the `<` symbols in line with multiple terms, but think it looks better when the first line is slightly indented (not required if a leading `-` is used). e.g.

[image]

## MWE

```
\documentclass{extarticle}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,physics}
\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
        \mu(x, y) = & \phantom{{}+{}} \sum_{k=1}^{2K} \\ % \\[-3.55em]
                    & + \sum_{k=1}^{2K}
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are few points I want to clarify:

1. The alignment tab `&` goes *before* the relation symbol, not after. You may take a look at [one of my previous answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/449772/164314) (shameless plug). If you follow this rule, then the use of `\phantomrel` (or other equivalences) is unavoidable.
2. The reason that you get undesirable `+` behavior is partly due to the incorrect use of the alignment tab `&`. After the `&`, the immediate following `+` is prepended by an implicit `{}` and so it is interpreted as a binary operator “plus”. <del>But you actually want it to be a unary operator “positive”, hence there will be spacing differences.</del> According to your example, you actually want a binary “plus”.
3. But since the `+` in `& + \sum...` is binary plus, why does it differ from `& \phantom{{}+{}} \sum...`? Well, although `{}+{}` produces a binary plus, the outer-layer `\phantom{...}` makes the whole thing into a `\mathord`. Note that `\sum` is a `\mathop`. Therefore, by rules, a thin space is used in the first line

   > `& \phantom{{}+{}} \sum...` becomes `{} <no space> mathord \, mathop`

   while a median space is used in the second line

   > `& + \sum...` becomes `{} \: mathbin \: mathop`

   so the spacing difference is expected.

With a combination of `\phantomrel` and `\phantombin` (together with a correct use of alignment tabs), this problem ceases to exist. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{extarticle}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\phantomrel[1]{\mathrel{\phantom{#1}}}
\newcommand\phantombin[1]{\mathbin{\phantom{#1}}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
        \mu(x, y) & =              {} \phantombin{+} \sum_{k=1}^{2K} \text{(Correct spacing)} \\ % \\[-3.55em]
                  & \phantomrel{=} {} +              \sum_{k=1}^{2K}
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image: binary spacing]

Comment: Can you avoid using the various `phantomrel{=}`. In the above example if I have several lines then this only requires a single `phantom`.

Comment: @oliversm I have updated my answer to include additional explanations. :)

Comment: Thanks for highlighting the implicit `{}` at the start of the left aligned columns, and point (3). Also the shameless plug was well deserved, and I'll change my `=&` usage to `&...`.

Comment: Sorry, but in the above example MWE you provide, are the empty `{}` just for clarity? (i.e. can they be removed?)

Comment: @oliversm If you want a binary plus, then the `{}` *cannot* be removed. This is because `& = +` creates an “impossible” combination: There is “no way” for a binary operator to follow a relation operator (again, by TeX’s rules), and thus this binary plus will be converted into an ordinary object, hence a unary positive. So `& = +` is equivalent to `{} mathrel mathord`. By adding an *explicit* `{}`, now we have `& = {} +` becoming `{} mathrel {} mathbin`. See [my other answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/434811/164314).

Comment: @oliversm I admit that my answer is quite involved. My intention is to encourage coding *semantically*. On the other hand, [egreg’s answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/451578/164314) is simpler (but I’d still suggest `... &= & & \phantombin{+} \sum...` for the first line; and `&  & & + \sum...` for the second line). Basically, `alignat*` inserts an *implicit* `{}` in every second column of a right-/left-aligned pair.

Comment: Thanks, that's cleared things up. I noticed that if I removed both `{}` they were correctly lined up, but on comparing them to the case with the `{}` I can see that without them they are slightly closer to the left, as can now be expected (being treated as `mathord`).

Answer (score 0):

A `\phantom` doesn't inherit the math type of the object it replaces. So `\phantom{=}` does not behave as a relation.

Besides, `=&` is generally not needed, but it should be `={}&` in case it becomes necessary.

However, there's a simpler solution.

## *Look, ma! No `\phantom`!*

```
\documentclass{extarticle}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
\mu(x, y) &= & & \sum_{k=1}^{2K} \\
          &  &+& \sum_{k=1}^{2K}
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]