# Alignment of terms within align environment

Tags: align, arrays, best-practices, phantom

> **The solutions below require up-to-date versions of LaTeX**
>
> ---
>
> When I tried to run the solutions below on my own machine I was not able to reproduce their results, but still got unwanted offsets. This was remedied by updating the latest distribution of LaTeX (2018). [As pointed out in this comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/455727/alignment-of-terms-within-align-environment/455733?noredirect=1#comment1146419_455733), this is because `amsmath` has had its `aligned` environment updated.

## Problem

I have several lines in a proof of mine, and I want to align several terms as shown:

## Output

[image]

I can achieve the following using `phantom` where needed:

## MWE

```
\documentclass{extarticle}

\usepackage{amsmath,bbm,bm,amssymb,amsthm,mathtools,cleveref,physics,letltxmacro}

% For usage in align environments. 
\newcommand\phantomrel[1]{\mathrel{\phantom{#1}}}
\newcommand\phantombin[1]{\mathbin{\phantom{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
A
& = \text{several short lines}\\
& = \text{some very long line which takes up most of the width of the page} \\ 
& = \text{several short lines} \\
& = B + \mathbb{E}(\abs{a + b + c + d}) \qquad \text{(typically too long for a single line)} \\
& \leq B + \mathbb{E}(\abs{a})  \\ % Using the triangle inequality.
& \phantomrel{\leq} \phantom{B} + \mathbb{E}(\abs{b}) \\
& \phantomrel{\leq} \phantom{B} + \mathbb{E}(\abs{c}) \\
& \phantomrel{\leq} \phantom{B} + \mathbb{E}(\abs{d}) \\
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

However, I am weary that this doesn't seem very scalable if I were to find an error and need to change `B` to a wider set of symbols, and would like to avoid falling into a copy/paste loop.

> I am using `phantomrel` and `phantombin` because of [a previous question of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/451557/106804)

Thinking of a better writing pattern my first two thoughts were:

- Use an `aligned` within the original `align`.
- Use an array.

## Using an array?

```
\begin{align*}
A
& = \text{several short lines}\\
& = \text{some very long line which takes up most of the width of the page} \\ 
& = \text{several short lines} \\
& = B + \mathbb{E}(\abs{a + b + c + d}) \qquad \text{(typically too long for a single line)} \\
& \leq B 
\begin{array}[t]{r}
{} + \mathbb{E}(\abs{a}) \\
{} + \mathbb{E}(\abs{b}) \\
{} + \mathbb{E}(\abs{c}) \\
{} + \mathbb{E}(\abs{d}) \\
\end{array}
\end{align*}
```

[image]

Although this has the `+` symbols too far offset because of the array margin.

### Use `aligned`?

```
\begin{align*}
A
& = \text{several short lines}\\
& = \text{some very long line which takes up most of the width of the page} \\ 
& = \text{several short lines} \\
& = B + \mathbb{E}(\abs{a + b + c + d}) \qquad \text{(typically too long for a single line)} \\
& 
\begin{aligned}
\leq B & + \mathbb{E}(\abs{a})  \\ % Using the triangle inequality.
& + \mathbb{E}(\abs{b}) \\
& + \mathbb{E}(\abs{c}) \\
& + \mathbb{E}(\abs{d}) 
\end{aligned}
\end{align*}
```

[image]

Almost, but the alignment is a bit off and I am not sure why.

#### Why not just use `aligned` for the whole thing?

I can't figure out how I would handle the very long lines without some selective use of `mathclap` (or similar), and would rather keep my use of ampersands to a minimum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a top-aligned `aligned` environment (pun intended) inside the `align*` environment.

Separately, I would also try to de-clutter the appearance of the equations by using fewer pairs of parentheses.

[image]

```
\documentclass{extarticle}

\usepackage{mathtools,bbm,bm,amssymb,amsthm,physics,
            letltxmacro,cleveref} % load 'cleveref' last
\DeclareMathOperator{\E}{\mathbb{E}} % expectation operator

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
A
&= \text{several short lines}\\
&= \text{some very long line which takes up most of the width of the page} \\ 
&= \text{several short lines} \\
&= B + \E\abs{a + b + c + d} \qquad \text{(typically too long for a single line)} \\
&\leq B 
\begin{aligned}[t]
   &+ \E \abs{a} \\ % by triangle inequality
   &+ \E \abs{b} \\
   &+ \E \abs{c} \\
   &+ \E \abs{d} 
\end{aligned}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Directly copying this code I get a result which is too far offset to the right ("similar" to the picture from when I tried to use `array`). Any idea why?

Comment: @oliversm - Please clarify what you mean by "too far offset to the right". For sure, the screenshot I posted, which is based on the code I posted, does not indicate any issues "similar to" one of the screenshots you posted.

Comment: Shortly after commenting I tried all 3 solutions and each one has some small offset and so I can only conclude there is something either off with my build or release version. Looking into it now.

Comment: @oliversm - How old is your TeX distribution, and when was it updated most recently? I seem to remember that either 1.5 or 2.5 years ago, the `amsmath` package (which is loaded automatically by the `mathtools` package) was updated. One of the main changes was the behavior of the `aligned` environment. Try inserting `\!` ("negative thinspace) immediately before `\begin{aligned}` in your code. If this resolves the alignment issue, then your TeX distribution still uses the old version of the `amsmath` package; my recommendation would be for you to update your TeX distribution.

Comment: I just tried it with a friend’s laptop with a 2018 distribution and it worked fine, so I will see if updating my version fixes the issue.

Comment: @oliversm - It's definitely starting to sound like your TeX distribution could benefit from a broad-based update.

Comment: Update to the latest version fixed this. I will add this detail to the OP.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

I added `{}` so you get relation spacing

```
\documentclass{extarticle}

\usepackage{amsmath,bbm,bm,amssymb,amsthm,mathtools,cleveref,physics,letltxmacro}

% For usage in align environments. 
\newcommand\phantomrel[1]{\mathrel{\phantom{#1}}}
\newcommand\phantombin[1]{\mathbin{\phantom{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
A
& = \text{several short lines}\\
& = \text{some very long line which takes up most of the width of the page} \\ 
& = \text{several short lines} \\
& = B + \mathbb{E}(\abs{a + b + c + d}) \qquad \text{(typically too long for a single line)} \\
& 
\begin{aligned}
{}\leq B & + \mathbb{E}(\abs{a})  \\ % Using the triangle inequality.
& + \mathbb{E}(\abs{b}) \\
& + \mathbb{E}(\abs{c}) \\
& + \mathbb{E}(\abs{d}) 
\end{aligned}
\end{align*}\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have no problem with aligned (measure precision: 0.1pt) and this very code. Unrelated: I removed the unnecessary packages.

```
\documentclass{extarticle}

\usepackage{bm,amssymb, amsthm, mathtools, cleveref, physics, letltxmacro}

% For usage in align environments.
\newcommand\phantomrel[1]{\mathrel{\phantom{#1}}}
\newcommand\phantombin[1]{\mathbin{\phantom{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
A
& = \text{several short lines}\\
& = \text{some very long line which takes up most of the width of the page} \\
& = \text{several short lines} \\
& = B + \mathbb{E}(\abs{a + b + c + d}) \qquad \text{(typically too long for a single line)} \\
& \leq B \begin{aligned}[t] & + \mathbb{E}(\abs{a}) \\ % Using the triangle inequality.
  & + \mathbb{E}(\abs{b}) \\
 & + \mathbb{E}(\abs{c}) \\
 & + \mathbb{E}(\abs{d})
\end{aligned}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]